# My Facebook account got blocked

Tags: facebook

My account is not deleted, but disabled instead. I've tried to contact Facebook, but all I get in the reply is that my FB account was blocked because I've breached Facebook TOS. The last letter said "This decision is final and cannot be appealed".

Any advice?